# xsd parsing and then making a dynamic form in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xsd

I am kind of new to the language and parsing. I have a xsd file, which I have to parse and generate a dynamic form with the values of the xsd file.

This is my xsd file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="app_bundle_name" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="app_name" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="app_xsd_version" type="xs:string" fixed="1.001"/>
  <xs:element name="configuration_version" type="xs:string"/>       
  <xs:element name="configuration_name" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:complexType name="connections1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ip_address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="8" />
      <xs:element name="port" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="8"/>
      <xs:element name="ssl" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="8"/>
      <xs:element name="device_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="8"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type=`enter code here`"xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="barcode_enter" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="barcode_next" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="close_session_on_exit" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="send_field_exit" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="field_exit_on_next" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="barcode_prefix" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="barcode_suffix" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="treat_enter_as_field_exit" type="xs:boolean" />
       <xs:element name="maintain_zoom_level" type="xs:boolean" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 <xs:complexType name="settings" />
</xs:schema>
```

Here name should be parsed as label.and type should become the type of control,for example string should become textbox and boolean should become select box with option yes or no.Fixed value will reflect in textboxes as their values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`simplexml_load_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) function to pull the data out of the file. Then loop over the `xs:sequence` element children, creating form elements as you go.

Comment: I have done this...

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->load('test.xsd');
 $xsdstring = "test.xsd";
 $t = new XMLREADER();
 $t->open($xsdstring);


    while($t->read())
 {
     if ($t->name === "xs:element")
            {
                    echo "-->" . $t->getAttribute('name') . "<br>\n";
            }
 }


but is not working as it should be

Comment: I managed to get your code to run when I modified line 14 of the XML: `<xs:element name="name" type=`enter code here`"xs:string" />` - the `type` attribute value is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally got the answer by myself...
So i am posting the code,may be anyone else could get help from the code.....

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_form.css" />

</head>
<body>
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();``
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->load('test.xsd');
 $xsdstring = "test.xsd";
 $t = new XMLREADER();
 $t->open($xsdstring);
    while($t->read())
 {
     if ($t->name === "xs:element")
            {
               echo '<div class="contain_div"><div class="lblname" >'. $t->getAttribute('name').'</div>';
                if($t->getAttribute('type')=='xs:string')
                    {
                        if($t->getAttribute('fixed')!='')
                            { 
                                echo '<div class="txtvaluestr"><input type="text" value="'.$t->getAttribute('fixed').'" readonly/></div></div>';    
                            }
                        else
                            { 
                                if($t->getAttribute('maxOccurs')!='')
                                {
                                    $max=$t->getAttribute('maxOccurs');
                                    echo '<div class="txtvaluestr"><input type="text"/></div><input style="margin-left:10px;" type="button" value="+" class="addButton"></div>';    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '<div class="txtvaluestr"><input type="text"/></div></div>';    
                                }
                            }
                    }   
                else if($t->getAttribute('type')=='xs:integer')
                      {
                        if($t->getAttribute('fixed')!='')


    enter code here

        {
                            echo '<div class="txtvalueint"><input type="text" value="'.$t->getAttribute('fixed').'" readonly/></div></div>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if($t->getAttribute('maxOccurs')!='')
                            {
                                echo '<div class="txtvalueint"><input type="text"/></div><input style="margin-left:10px;" type="button" value="+" class="addButton"></div>';   
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<div class="txtvalueint"><input type="text"/></div></div>';   
                            }
                        } 
                    }  
                else if($t->getAttribute('type')=='xs:boolean')
                      {
                        if($t->getAttribute('fixed')!='')
                        {
                            echo '<div class="txtvaluebool"><select id="opt"><option>'.$t->getAttribute('fixed').'</option></select></div></div>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<div class="txtvaluebool"><select id="opt"><option>Yes</option><option>no</option></select></div></div>';  
                        }  
                    }  
            }
 }
?>
</body>
<html>
```